# Moved to new server - Expresso editor - denied file access?

Tags: migration, server-migration, expresso-toolbar

I've just moved an **EE v2.7.2** site to a new server, following the EE-docs thoroughly. Verified all paths and file/folder permissions.

Everything works well until i try to edit or publish an entry, getting the error message below.

To get a WYSIWYG editor i'm using Expresso field types for my 'summary' and 'body' fields, and as soon I write or edit in one of these fields it is not possible to submit without the error. If I use only the other non-Expresso fields there is no error message.

Everything was working perfectly on the previous server.

Any suggestions?

[image: Error message - access denied]

Comment: Could you provide a translation of the error message into English?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a **mod_security** issue. Please check if your host is running it.

You can turn off mod_security by adding below code to `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```